# How to set Android Header as full width image in React Native

Tags: react-native

How do I get the image to fill the appbar. I created a custom component as below:

```
class HeaderImage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
                <Image style={styles.image}
                       resizeMode={'cover'}
                       source={require('../../assets/images/header1.jpg')}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imageWrapper: {
        backgroundColor:"red",
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        height:120
    },
    image: {
        flex: 1,
    },
});


export default HeaderImage;
```

Then I added it to the StackNavigator

```
  <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}
                              options={{headerTitle: props => <HeaderImage {...props} />}}
                />
```

But it doesnt fill the width.It just looks like its floating

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `headerBackground` to cover the whole app bar.

```js
// HeaderImage.js

export class HeaderImage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Image
                style={{ height: "100%", flex: 1 }}
                source={require('../../assets/images/header1.jpg')} 
            />
        );
    }
}

// Navigation.js

// ...
    <Stack.Screen 
        name="Dashboard" 
        component={Dashboard}
        options={{
            headerBackground: () => <HeaderImage />
        }}
    /> 
// ...
```

Comment: This works great.The only challenge I have now is how to make the header have the height of 120 as above

Comment: You should apply `headerStyle: { height: 120 }` to your options :)

Comment: Worked like a charm